# Is looping in Excel VBA slower than in other languages such as C/C++?

Tags: excel, vba

I am not talking about slow looping in Excel VBA due to the overhead relating to reading and writing to cells. What I am talking about is looping "in memory" using variables/arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have two loops that do roughly the same thing, C/C++ is *very likely* to be faster since it will be compiled to machine code, while VBA has the overhead of the VBA interpreter and Excel itself.  If you plan to *marshal data* to C/C++ to do the loops, there will be some overhead for the marshaling; how much depends on how you choose to do that.

However, don't choose a platform simply because *loops are faster*, choose a platform that fits the solution and makes you the most efficient.

In my experience, it's not the *looping* that is slow, but what's *inside* the loop that's slow.  As you presumably have discovered, cell-by-cell access is MUCH slower in excel than direct array access.

If you need to know *how much faster*, measure it!  Create a simple VBA loop and an equivalent loop (or as close as you can get) in C or C++ and see which one is faster (and how much).

Comment: +1 This answer promotes the idea of testing the solution to fit _your_ programming style.

Comment: One note that is relevant for UDFs in Excel is that there is a bug that causes the VBE title bar to refresh every time it is calculated, which can cause significant performance issues with a UDF that loops (i.e. a recursive function that you're calling from a cell in a workbook)